# Setting password of the new user in non interactive way in shell script on ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu-18.04

I have created a new user on Ubuntu. I want to know how to set the password of the new user in a non-interactive way in a shell script on Ubuntu?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [ubuntu.se], as it is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1:**

```sh
echo "username:newpass"|chpasswd
```

Modifying the username and newpass values.

**Option 2:**

```sh
echo -e "v3rystrongpassword" | passwd username
```

**Option 3:**

```sh
echo "v3rystrongpassword" | passwd username --stdin
```

Comment: Thanks Lemon  for the response . I added the code below in shell script

Comment: sudo useradd tim2
sudo usermod -aG sudo tim2
echo -e "tim123" |  passwd tim2
id tim2

Comment: I get this when script is executed :passwd: You may not view or modify password information for tim2.
uid=1003(tim2) gid=1003(tim2) groups=1003(tim2),27(sudo)

Comment: Any thoughts how to fix this ?

Comment: echo -e "tim123" | sudo   passwd tim2  gives the same error

Comment: I guess you just don’t have permission. This is your Linux box, correct?

Comment: I am able to create a new user . I am running on Ubuntu 18.0.4 . Script is run by ubuntu user that has sudo permissions

Comment: There is no `--stdin` option for `passwd`

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following, which takes into account the fact that `passwd` will ask you to re-type the password after the first time you enter it.

```
printf "<password>\n<password>" | sudo passwd <username>
```

`<username>` and `<password>` are meant to be replaced with the actual username and password, respectively.

Comment: Similarly `echo -e "<password>\n<password>\n" | sudo passwd <username>` worked for me